# Tracing the origin of the clefs

Tags: history

In written music and preceding the key signature there is always a symbol, it is named the [clef](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clef) and it indicates the [pitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_(music)) of the notes written on the [stave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staff_(music)). There are quite a few different ones which include the G-clef, C-clef, F-clef, as well as variations of these. I am intrigued by their appearances and wish to learn more about when they had originated and about their significances during musical reference.

Comment: dup of https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/32161/grand-staff-using-the-bass-clef-and-treble-alto-tenor-clef/41780#41780 https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clef

Comment: this only mentions the Treble Alto-Tenor Clef symbols, further it does not delve into the historical

Comment: Welcome to SE Music :) You didn't actually formulate a specific question we can answer to. As it's currently written it does not fit the format of the site and risks being closed. Have you read https://music.stackexchange.com/tour ?

Comment: Could you help me formulate my question better? I am interested in the years they were implemented into the current modal system.

Comment: @aitía Did you see the "History" section of the linked Wikiepdia article?

Comment: The G and F clefs are just the letters G and F in a stylised form. Their origin is the alphabet.